# Django Rest Framework: Find URL for hyperlinked model

Tags: python, rest, url, routes, django-rest-framework

I'm using using Django Rest Framework's HyperlinkedModelSerializer, ModelViewset, and DefaultRouter, and end up with good URLs like this: `http://localhost:8000/api/users/1`.
I would like to, given a user id, find the fully-qualified url for that user without hard-coding anything. Given 53, I want `http://localhost:8000/api/users/1`, and the host should change when I move to production.

```
# from urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', shared_views.UserViewSet)


# from models.py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''
    endpoint for viewing/editing users
    '''
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


# from serializers.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')
```

How can I do this? I tried: `reverse(UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), args=[request.user.id])` but got this error:

> Reverse for 'shared.views.UserViewSet' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: you don't need to create the `url `. The `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` by default will create the url for you. check the api response json you should see a url for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Anush said, I can use the serializer to get the URL. The request needs to be passed in a particular way as a keyword argument (see below):

```
class OwnedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ''' ModelViewSets that use hyperlinked model serializers
        can inherit this to automatically
        set `owner` = current user. 
    '''
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serialized_owner = UserSerializer(request.user, context={'request': request})
        request.data['owner'] = serialized_owner.data['url']
        return super(OwnedViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Looking back on this, I am even more struck by how Django Rest Framework does the best it can with bad abstractions.